# Combine case statement result with

Tags: sql-server-2008, case

I have a value that I need to transform when it starts with 3, and then combine that value with another field to create a final value.

Code so far:

```
  ,case  
    when b.thing like '3%' then '000'
    else b.thing
    end as 'Thing'
```

and then I'd like to use the 'Thing' value to create 'Thing+b.Stuff'. I tried to add 'b.Stuff' to the else statement but only returned 'b.Thing'.

I am thinking I maybe need to create a subquery/inline view but I just can't see how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just add b.stuff to your code (assuming they are the same data type)

```
,case  
    when b.thing like '3%' then '000'+b.stuff
    else b.thing+b.stuff
    end as 'Thing'
```

Comment: Awesome. Worked great. Thanks!